# Does Windows 8 suspend Desktop and all applications when I exit pressing the Win key?

Tags: windows-8-preview

1. Does *Windows 8 consumer preview 64-bit* suspend the Desktop with all applications when I exit pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd> key?
2. Does *Steam* always start a game with suspended desktop applications?

Answer (score 3):

Desktop and desktop applications don't get suspended like Metro applications do.